# Largest Number With Non-Decreasing Digits

Tags: algorithm, performance, number-theory

What is the largest positive integer(call it k) less than or equal to N such that all digits of integer k are in non decreasing order?

**Constraints:**
1 <= **N** <= 10^18
1 <= k <= N
Time Limit: **8** sec

One of the solutions is checking all the values starting from N-1 (i.e., N-1, N-2, N-3, .....) till I find the number with non decreasing digits.
But this can be done in given time limit only if N <= 10^10. 
 It exceeds the time limit for given constraints (N <= 10^18).

Comment: Look at the analysis for problem B from Google Codejam 2017 Qualification round: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/3264486/dashboard#s=a

Comment: I think you're supposed to show at least your attempt at solving the problem, rather than posting a question and asking others to solve it for you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple greedy approach will be scanning the number from the right and if you find a digit that is less than the digit on its left then, decrease the digit on the left by `1` and replace all the digits from current digit to the rightmost digit with `9`.

**Ex:**

```
132 -> 1 3 2

2 < 3 so replace 2 by 9 and decrease 3 by 1
```

You can do this because the resulting number will definitely be smaller than the original. And also we want to maximize the number so we are replacing the digit with largest possible digit `9` and decreasing the left digit with least possible digit `1` in order to maximize the resulting number.

Repeat this process for all the digits to the left until you find a valid number. And yes check for corner cases (leading zeros).

for number `1332`

`1332` -> `1329` -> `1299`(valid number)

so the answer will be `1299`.

Comment: using this algorithm, when decrease process takes place he must also look backward to check if decreased number satisfies the rule. ex. `1332` -> `1299`, not `1329`

Comment: yes, that is necessary, you have to repeat the process until you find a valid number while scanning from right to left.